# Setting keyboard layout on SSH server

Tags: ssh, keyboard-layout

I normally type on a Dvorak keyboard, but often login to an SSH server from computers that won't let me change the keyboard layout.  Is there any way to set a keyboard layout on the server-side to translate QWERTY input into Dvorak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Input from keystrokes are handled by your SSH terminal application on the client machine, not by anything on the server.

The `loadkeys` configuration as suggested by @JustinPearce will change the keyboard layout on the console of the server when you log in there physically (console-tty, non-SSH).

Answer (score 1):

I've just written a Python script that should do what you want: https://github.com/ssb22/bits-and-bobs/blob/master/dvpty.py

Please note the comment about the Tab key.  As the script is running on the server, it has no way to tell the difference between Tab and Ctrl-I (which maps to Ctrl-C in Dvorak), so by default if you hit Tab you get Ctrl-C, which is not great for command-line tab completion.  You can alternatively put it into a mode to leave Tab as it is at the expense of having to press Dvorak Ctrl-I (QWERTY Ctrl-G) to get Ctrl-C, or you can set it not to remap the control keys at all.

Comment: +1 for effort, but this does seem very much like making a dog walk on its hind legs. I presume you could also set lots of bash bindings to do the same thing.

Comment: Not sure how well bash bindings work in applications.  I've used dvpty.py in bash, Emacs, Joe and Mutt, which pretty much covers what I want to do from the public library computer using a TOTP login over WebSSH (their software has a blanket restriction on all settings changes and non-library applications but I can basically do what I want in the browser; yes I could probably have remapped the keyboard by modifying WebSSH's Javascript but dvpty.py seemed easier and also covers the case of other SSH clients available but no keyboard-layout changes permitted)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
loadkeys /path/to/keymaps/dvorak.map.gz
```

Just change `dvorak.map.gz` to the file name for the dvorak keymap. You can even set this up as a bash script to run when your user logs in via the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you can work in Emacs:

```
emacs --eval='(set-input-method "english-dvorak")'
```

and press Control-Backslash to toggle between the QWERTY and Dvorak input methods (need to do this for each buffer you visit in the Emacs session).  It works for editing files, and it works with Emacs's `M-x shell` (line-mode command shell), but it doesn't work with Emacs's `M-x term` terminal.  Also, `set-input-method` does not remap the control keys.